# BeautifulSoup not getting output

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So, I want to get the football stats out of the table but first, I want to get the table with soup. This is where I have a problem, that I always get an empty list.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.eredmenyek.com/foci/nemetorszag/bundesliga/'

oldal = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(oldal.text, "lxml")

review_table_elem = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'stats-table-container'})

print(review_table_elem)
```

And the HTML code is:

a lot of divs above here

```
<div class="stats-table-container"><table id="table-type-1" class="stats-table stats-main table-1" title=""> //And here is the table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative to selenium is [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/). Since you are already familiar with requests you will be able to pick this up easily.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.eredmenyek.com/foci/nemetorszag/bundesliga/')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, "html.parser")
review_table_elem = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'stats-table-container'})
print(review_table_elem)
```

Comment: This is very cool, Bitto.. I was not familiar with `requests-html` until now. I will leave my answer as an alternative, but I like this solution!

Answer (score 0):

The page you're interacting with depends heavily on javascript to render its content. The data you're looking for will not be in the response you get with `requests` because it doesn't evaluate javascript.

To achieve this, you will need to use something that does, like Selenium WebDriver. Here is a solution using it and a headless instance of Chrome. In addition to installing the `selenium` module, you will need to download [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and change the following code to point it to the location you extracted it to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options, executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
)

try:
    driver.get("https://www.eredmenyek.com/foci/nemetorszag/bundesliga/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

    for row in soup.select(".stats-table-container tr"):
        print("\t".join([e.text for e in row.select("td")]))

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
1.      Borussia Dortmund       20      15      4       1       51:20   49            
2.      Mönchengladbach 20      13      3       4       41:18   42            
3.      Bayern München  20      13      3       4       44:23   42            
4.      RB Leipzig      20      11      4       5       38:18   37            
5.      Frankfurt       20      9       5       6       40:27   32   
...
```